# javascript library designed for easy building of the web-based contests

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

I am looking for a javascript library designed for easy building of the web-based contests (such as photocontests, essays contest, video contest and so on).
My web application is using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html).

I found several example of these kinds of web applications such as:

1) http://www.wufoo.com/
2) http://www.crowdtogether.com/create-a-contest

Regarding Bootstrap there is a section where you can Customize variables, but then you need to download the style.
Actually I am looking for a real time solution where you can:
1) login
2) create the context online 
3) save the result on the server.

My questions are:

1) Even if there is no such javascripit library to make the cline-side job, what could be the closest solution?

2) I think that the cline-side job is quite complicated to accomplish by means of a general javascript library.
   So maybe a good starting point should be having a javascript library which is able to read css properties and edit/move dom contents. Any ideas?

Thanks.

P.S.:
As suggested by @AhmadAlfy, `Backbone.js`, `Backbone.Marionette`, `underscore` and `jquery` will be useful for this kind of application.
Any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

Well I would assume that :

1. You need all of the client logic in JavaScript.
2. You will update parts of the UI on change to data.
3. Templating will be done on client side.

You'll need :

1. An MVC like pattern to keep the code clean
2. Templating engine.
3. A way to manage events and callbacks
4. A way to preserve browser's history (Update URL - Back button)

I would recommend you check [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) . It gives structure to web applications by providing:

1. Models with key-value binding and custom events
2. Collections with a rich API
3. Views with declarative event handing

Leave Backbone to handle the data and use jQuery and underscore (bundled with Backbone) for templating

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer. Of course Backbone.js + Backbone.Marionette + underscore and jquery will be useful for this kind of application. any other idea? thanks

Comment: If you need some framework to facilitate rapid development I recommend you use Bootstrab. Consistent layout, responsive and easy to learn